# how to make d3 gantt chart installable to other computer?

Tags: php, jquery, d3.js, drupal-6, gantt-chart

i have this problem that my d3 gantt chart needs to be INSTALLABLE to other computers. What i mean is that even if you copy the codes to other computer the chart should run without any problem. I have pinpoint that the problem occur in this part of code

```
       d3.json("http://localhost/drupal/mini/pm/json", function(error,json){
```

i need the "PATH" of the data automatically change where ever pc my program is installed
is there a way to do this????????  thanks for the people who will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to ..

```
d3.json("index.php?q=mini/pm/json", function(error,json){ ..
```